# Using gather to tidy dataset in R- attributes are not identical

Tags: r, plyr, tidyr

My end goal is to do ratios between two values (T/D) with my dataset, but it seemed like the best way to do that would be to tidy my dataset using something like tidyr. I have been trying to use gather and separate but had some hiccups. The data looks like this:

> 

```
head(df9)
>  GeneID     D1     T1      D2     T2     D3     T3     D4     T4      D5      T5     D6     T6     D7     T7     D8     T8
>1    A2M 8876.5 8857.9 10246.8 9453.9 6279.6 3846.5 8735.3 6609.9 7732.95  2452.4 8705.2   6679 7510.5 4318.3 8957.7 4092.4
>2   ABL1 2120.8 1664.9    2525 1546.4   1993 1713.7 1849.7 1761.9  2297.7  2462.5 2698.2 1975.8 2480.3 1694.6   2471 1784.1
>3   ACP1 1266.6 1347.1  910.95  725.1 1327.6 1589.5   1175 1086.9  1187.3 1065.15   1080 1048.2 1213.8 1337.9  831.5  814.1
```

But I want it to look like this:

```
> GeneID  pt.num  type value 
>ASM      1        D    8876 
>ASM      1       T    8857
```

I tried the following. But I keep getting errors. Warning message: attributes are not identical across variables; they will be dropped.

```
gather(df9, pt.num.type, value, 2:17, -GeneID)
separate(pt.num.type, c("pt.num","type", 1))
```

When I get my data clean, I want to use the following to get the T/D ratios.

```
df10 <- ddply(df9, .(type), transform, Ratio=T/D)
```

Any advice on cleaning my data and running the function would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Can you do `dput(df9)` and paste the output here?

Comment: It is enormous. So something must be wrong with my data.frame. R Studio lists the subset "sample" as 3 obs of 17 variables, but the dput(sample) is too large to post here.

Comment: The original data file has 859 obs of 28 variables.

Comment: Somewhere along the way- my data was converted to a factor, preventing me from doing the calculations. Once I reverted to an previous version that was numeric, it worked! I am new to this and found it very frustrating. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you were close, you just misplaced the `sep` argument:

```
gather(df9, pt.num.type, value, 2:17)
separate(pt.num.type, c("type", "pt.num"), sep=1)
```

Using `dplyr` you could do something like:

```
df9 %>% 
  gather(pt.num.type, value, 2:5) %>%
  separate(pt.num.type, c("type", "pt.num"), sep=1) %>%
  group_by(GeneID, type) %>%
  summarise(sum = sum(value))

#   GeneID type  sum
# 1    A2M    D  989
# 2    A2M    T 1033
# 3   ABL1    D  464
# 4   ABL1    T  170
# 5   ACP1    D 1036
# 6   ACP1    T  738
```

Then if you're trying to get the ratio (depending on how you are separating), you could do something like:

```
df9 %>% 
  gather(pt.num.type, value, 2:5) %>%
  separate(pt.num.type, c("type", "pt.num"), sep=1) %>%
  spread(type, value) %>%
  mutate(Ratio = D/T)

#   GeneID pt.num   D   T      Ratio
# 1    A2M      1 887  88 10.0795455
# 2    A2M      2 102 945  0.1079365
# 3   ABL1      1 212  16 13.2500000
# 4   ABL1      2 252 154  1.6363636
# 5   ACP1      1 126  13  9.6923077
# 6   ACP1      2 910 725  1.2551724
```